# VS Code Python extension startup environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, vscode-extensions

I have recently changed computers and I can't fix this 'issue'.
I'm working with Python now and of course I have installed the official Python extension for VS Code. There are options to activate the Python virtual environment at startup as you know, but it is using the `Scripts\Activate.ps1` command to do it and it fails always. It works by using manually the `Scripts\activate` command.

How can I set the Python extension to use the activate command instead of `Activate.ps1`?

My default terminal is `cmd` in Visual Studio Code and I'm on Windows 11.

I do not want to switch to the Powershell terminal if possible. I'm fine the CMD.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Marko! I'm going to help you get your question into our style.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the command that VS Code's Python extension uses to activate the virtual environment by modifying the `python.pythonPath` setting in your VS Code `settings.json` file. Here's how to do it:

1. Open VS Code and go to File -> Preferences -> Settings
2. Search for `python.pythonPath`
3. Scroll down to the "Python Path" section and click "Edit in settings.json"
4. In the settings.json file, add the following:

   `"python.pythonPath": "~/mypath/virtualenv/Scripts/activate"`
5. Save and restart

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer! It seems like something is wrong. I can't find a python path section, and if i add manually that line inside the json file, the editor says 'configuration setting unknown'. Am i missing something?

Comment: @MarkoLizZo I think you must be using a different version from me. What version are you on? Do you see "Edit in settings.json"? Also, run a quick `pip list` to check running environments

Comment: Latest version of VS Code / Python since my Pc is new. I can see the Edit in settings.json, but overlaying on the python.pythonPath string i get the message configuration setting unknow. Shutted down the environment now and i can only see the default packages as expected with the pip list command. Everything is fine but VS Code is still using the Activate.ps1 command..

Comment: @MarkoLizZo Sounds like either the path in  `python.pythonPath` is wrong or it's being overwritten. Try to verify it. If it looks correct then try setting the "terminal.integrated.shell.windows" setting in your VS Code settings.json file to "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe".

Comment: I'm using the "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt" setting cause the "terminal.integrated.shell.windows" is deprecated. VS Code is using the CMD as expected, but there's something wrong with the python extension which is using the Powershell command.. Not a big problem tho, i can activate the env manually but....